# A Perl system call must send exactly both characters single & double quote ' "

Tags: shell, perl, ksh, cleartool

A Perl system call must send the following string to the `UnixShell`:

```
'"XYZ"'
```

In my Perl script I have used the following command:

```
system("cleartool mkattr -replace ATTRIBUTE '"$attribute"' lbtype:$label");
```

Everything is well passed to the `Shell Unix`, except both uses of the quote character:

```
'
```

Indeed,

```
cleartool mkattr -replace ATTRIBUTE
```

The above command is passed as it is exactly what I want.
The Perl variables $attribute and $label are well interpreted.
But I don't know what to do to obtain exactly:

```
'"XYZ"'
```

Here `XYZ` is the value of the Perl variable $attribute
OS is `AIX (Unix)` and `Shell` is `ksh`. cleartool is the command line interface of Clearcase but **no Clearcase skill is necessary** to fix my problem.

Comment: The shown Perl code with `system(…)`  shouldn't even compile since the `"` before the `$attribute` variable should terminate the previous string. Are you sure that's the code you are using?

Comment: How are you not getting a runtime error?  Are you sure it's not `system("clear ... BUTE '" . $attribute ...`  You can't concatenate strings with no operator like that.

Comment: It's not clear from my question I WANT TO pass  '"XYZ"' not "XYZ".

Comment: I have to wonder if you *do* have to send that exact string. It looks like you are trying to build up a command line, and confusing literal quotes with syntactic quotes. `system("cleartool", "mkattr", "-replace", "ATTRIBUTE", $attribute, "lbtype$label")` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to execute a system command and don't have to use any shell syntax like redirects, it's usually better and safer to use the list form of `system`:

```perl
system(
    'cleartool',  'mkattr', '-replace', 'ATTRIBUTE',
    qq{"$attribute"}, qq{lbtype:$label}
);
# or, if you really want to pass both types of quotes:
system(
    'cleartool',  'mkattr', '-replace', 'ATTRIBUTE',
    qq{'"$attribute"'}, qq{lbtype:$label}
);
```

See [perldoc -f system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)

It's not clear from your question if you want to pass `'"XYZ"'` or `"XYZ"`.

Comment: `qq{"$attribute"}` can be replaced with `$attribute`.

Comment: @shawnhcorey that would be something different. It depends if the OP really wants to pass the quotes to the program or not

Comment: @shawnhcorey It is pretty clear. The heading says _system call must send exactly both characters '"_ Later in the actual body, he also states _except both uses of the quote character:_

Comment: @GerhardBarnard the OP says `'"XYZ"'` should be passed to the *shell*. but it's not clear (at least to me) what `cleartool` should end up with.

Comment: @tinita Agreed. When a string of quotes appear in a shell command, I suspect an XY problem.

Comment: Both uses of the quote character means exactly that, both single and double quotes, just as mentioned in the heading and twice in the actual answer.

Comment: @shawncorey: The question may be unclear, but `qq{"$attribute"}` is certainly not equivalent to `$attribute`. Your comment is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

See ["Quote and Quote like Operators"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) and use `qq{...}`:

```
system(qq{cleartool mkattr -replace ATTRIBUTE '"$attribute"' lbtype:$label});
```

`qq{...}` is exactly like `"..."` except you can then use double quotes `"` in your string *without escaping* them.

You can use any character directly after the `qq` and must then use the same character to denote the end-of-string, i.e. `qqX...X` would work the same way. You would run into problems if your string contains Xes, so don't do that.

You can also use *paired* characters as delimiter (`{}`, `()`, `<>`) which is what you usually will see.

Comment: I learned a lot from your answer, thanks a lot. But the result is always the same. I lose the character: '     , it is replaced by: "    , I tested many other possibilities... escape the quote, the double quote, both... qq keeps everything even back slash but not the single quote.

Comment: @Martin: That isn't true. `qq//` doesn't retain backslashes and won't remove single quotes. Try printing the values before you pass them to `system`.