# Use mkattr in perl script (Unix env)?

Tags: perl, ksh, clearcase, cleartool

Clearcase command line mkattr needs to wrap variable $bug_num between single quote + quote + $varible + quote + single quote, like this:

```
cleartool mkattr -replace BUGNUM '"$bug_num"' clearcase_file
```

How to make a call of the command cleartool mkattr in a Perl script in Unix env?
Env is Unix AIX and ksh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47330424/6309):

> If you want to execute a system command and don't have to use any shell syntax like redirects, it's usually better and safer to use the list form of system:

```
system(
    'cleartool',  'mkattr', '-replace', 'BUGNUM ',
    qq{"$bug_num"}, qq{clearcase_file}
);
# or, if you really want to pass both types of quotes:
system(
    'cleartool',  'mkattr', '-replace', 'BUGNUM ',
    qq{'"$bug_num"'}, qq{clearcase_file}
);
```

Or:

```
system(qq{cleartool mkattr -replace BUGNUM '"$bug_num"' clearcase_file});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. if it works i will vote your post tomorrow.

Comment: Great! which syntax did you chose?